# Keep arrays at same size if array 0 changes

Tags: python, arrays

So I have an array which looks like this: `A = [[],[0]]`
Through my script the first array will change in size so it will look something like this:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],[0]]
```

What I want is that everytime array `A[0]` changes in size, `A[1]` should change in size too but with each entry being `0`.
So in the end I want it to look like this:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],[0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Hi! How do you change the size of the first array?
We need code.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want a mechanism so that every time your code adds to `A[0]` then `A[1]` will automatically also change? Why don't you just write your code so that both subarrays are changed together? Or just check the length of `A[1]` when needed? Do you really need lists, or would a custom class suffice? We need more explanation of your purpose.

Comment: You mean `list`*

Comment: What about if `array.size < index` then consider it as 0.

Comment: You can probably get this behavior in your own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this "automatically" - you need to define logic to update other sublists when you update one sublist. For example, you can use a custom function to append to a sublist *and* expand other sublists:

```
A = [[], [0]]

def append_and_expand(data, idx, val):
    data[idx].append(val)
    n = len(data[idx])
    for lst in data:
        lst.extend([0]*(n-len(lst)))
    return data

res = append_and_expand(A, 0, 3)  # [[3], [0]]
res = append_and_expand(A, 0, 4)  # [[3, 4], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: This is good (except for the use of `L` as a parameter` -- why not `lst`?)

Comment: @FHTMitchell, :) Any recommendations? Is it because it's a capital letter ? or not verbose, e.g. `lst_of_lsts` would work

Comment: Single capital letter variables make me cry :'(. As I said, `lst` would be fine, as would `lst_of_lsts`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, Got it, I changed to `data`, I *try* to avoid small `l` in general because in many fonts it's confused with `I` (capital "I").

Comment: yeah - `l` is also confusable with `1` in some fonts

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [[],[0]]

print(A)
if not A[0]:    # To check if the first list is empty
    A[1] = []   # Set the second one to null
    for i in range(1, 5):     # Some iteration/method of yours already working here
        A[0] = A[0] + [i]     # Some iteration/method of yours already working here
        A[1] = A[1] + [0]     # Adding the `0` each time inside that iteration

print(A)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[], [0]]

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```